# Python Window Executable Error: LoadLibrary: Pyinstaller: FormatMessageW failed

Tags: python

I am tasked with trying to get this python executable working on a client's server. Our python developer left and being a .NET guy I am not sure how Python works. Here is the error message:

```
Error Loading Python DLL 'C:\users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\3\_mEI\python39.dll
No error message generated.
FormatMessageW: The parameter is incorrect.
LoadLibrary: Pyinstaller: FormatMessageW failed.
```

I am working on an older Windows Server (2008 r2). This what I tried so far

1. Uninstall/Reinstall Python
2. Tried to recompile the python executable
3. Run through command prompt with parameters
4. Ran the executable on local machine, but the error does not show.

What are some other steps?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install **Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015**?

Download link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145

I got it from this answer:
[Pyinstaller - Error loading Python DLL - FormatMessageW failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54214600/pyinstaller-error-loading-python-dll-formatmessagew-failed)

Comment: yea, i forgot to mention that. that was the first thing I tried.